# WP custom fields plugin - which tables affected?

Tags: wordpress

I am updating a live site from production server. I don't have access to PHPMyadmin. I can choose certain database tables to move from the production site's admin panel to the live one. Question: **Which Db tables are used by WP plugin "Custom Fields"** (or - "Advanced custom fields") ?
I know only one table which is **wp_postmeta** but importing this table alone doesn't work (custom fields don't appear on the live site). And I cannot import all tables because of the content and other settings that are up to date on the live site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fields was saving in e.g. wp_postmeta. Var_dump get_post_meta() to see all of them connected to specific post.
BTW - you don't need PHPMyadmin to see DB :)

Comment: Dzieki, Tomasz! Just to explain a bit more: I have added a custom field called "show date' which is "true/false" type. It is supposed to be on the post (edit) page (and it is on the production server). I have imported "wp_postmeta" table from the production to live server but it is not showing up on the live server on the edit post page. So, posisbly, I had to import additional tables?

Comment: Importing "wp_postmeta" is not enough - its only meta. You must import ACF fields or create in ACF groups fields, with fields and conditions as before.

Comment: That's why I mentioned I didn;'t have access to the Db to analyze which fields are new and where those had been added. So again - just t summarize. We have a database with 666 posts. Each post has its own record "show date / show no date". Also the custom field called "show_date". What tables (all DB compoments) shoudl I move from the working production server to have teh same result on the live one?
The bloody WP with its plug-ins is beyond my comprehension but that's what I have to do tnight anyway =((
Thanks for your answers, man! have a wonderful weekend

Comment: Copying  tables from one environment to another in some issues could be dangerous. As i said before, for the best result use default WP importer for ACF (especially when ACF is ver 4). Im not sure if this information will help you, but ACF fields group was saved as custom post type - you could find them in wp_posts where post_type = 'acf'. Each field was saved in wp_postmeta in meta_key = 'fields_xxxNumbersxxxx'.